# .htaccess rewrite rule for redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I've been fighting this for a while and can't seem to make it work.  My old system used a lot of query strings to render pages but they are no longer necessary.  My url is below:

- OLD URL: www.example.com/links.php?section=5&catid=52
- NEW URL: www.example.com/mhfs/links

The name links is coincidental and not necessarily from the old pages name.  I need to check which section and catid is present and redirect them to the appropriate page from what it is.  I tried the following but this just seems to do nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^links.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^section=5$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^catid=52$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mhfs/links? [R=301]
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: This belongs on servfault, not stackoverflow.
I haven't got the rank to move it, but you ought to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You must turn the rewrite engine on for it to work.
You probably don't want the regex start symbol on the replacement:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond ...

RewriteRule ...

Comment: Sorry.. I knew I'd forget to add some details.  I have a lot of other rules running on this file so I have the rewrite engine on, but it seems to be when I get to multiple variables that nothing I do is working.